# Ajax responseText URL not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, google-visualization

I am trying to query mysql db and put the results in the chart. It has two file `index.php` and `getpiechartdata.php`. Both of this file are on my remote server in `/public_html/` folder.

I am not sure whether `index.php` is even calling my `getpiechartdata.php` script. Although the data returned (when directly calling data.php) from the `getpiechartdata.php` looks like this.

```
{ "cols": 
  [ {"id":"","label":"Libraries","pattern":"","type":"string"}, 
    {"id":"","label":"Count","pattern":"","type":"number"} ], 
  "rows": [ {"c":[{"v":"/usr/lib64/crti.o","f":null},
                  {"v":77005,"f":null}]}, 
            {"c":[{"v":"/usr/lib64/crtn.o","f":null},
                  {"v":77005,"f":null}]}, 
            {"c":[{"v":"/lib64/ld-2.11.3.so","f":null},
                  {"v":53922,"f":null}]}, 
            {"c":[{"v":"/lib64/libc-2.11.3.so","f":null},
                  {"v":53922,"f":null}]}]
}
```

I am not sure how to test whether the url: ajax call to my php script is working or not. I will be glad if someone can give me some pointer on this.

```
<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart,table package
   google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart','table']});

  function drawItems(syshost) {

          // document.write(syshost);

          var jsonPieChartData = $.ajax({url: "getpiechartdata.php",data: "q="+syshost,dataType:"json", async: false}).responseText;

          // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
          var piechartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonPieChartData);

          // Instantiate and draw our pie chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(piechartdata, {
          width: 700,
          height: 500,
          chartArea: { left:"5%",top:"5%",width:"90%",height:"90%" }
          });
  }
   </script>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Welcome to UTKA! </h1>

  <form>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Most Used Libraries Till Date</legend>
  <p>Select Syshost
  <!-- <select name="users" onchange="drawItems(this.value)">   -->
  <select name="users" onchange="drawItems(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">

<?php

try {
    include (__DIR__ ."/include/conn.php");
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(build_syshost) AS syshost  
            FROM utka_link
            ORDER BY syshost ASC";

    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

    foreach($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
        echo '<option value='. $row['syshost'] . '>'. $row['syshost'] . '</option>';
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
</select></fieldset></form>
</body>
</html>
```

getpiechartdata.php

```
<?php
//  $q=$_GET["q"];
  $q='darter';;
try {
        include (__DIR__ ."/include/conn.php");
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT object_path AS Libraries, module_name AS ModuleName, count(date) AS Count 
                FROM utka_link, join_link_object, utka_object 
                WHERE build_syshost='$q' AND 
                utka_link.link_id = join_link_object.link_id AND 
                join_link_object.obj_id = utka_object.obj_id 
                GROUP BY object_path 
                ORDER BY Count DESC
                LIMIT 10";

        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();

        $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo "{ \"cols\": [ {\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"Libraries\",\"pattern\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\"}, {\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"Count\",\"pattern\":\"\",\"type\":\"number\"} ], \"rows\": [ ";

        $total_rows = $query->rowCount();
        $row_num = 0;

        foreach($result as $row){
                $row_num++;
                if ($row_num == $total_rows){
                        echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"" . $row['Libraries'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":" . $row['Count'] . ",\"f\":null}]}";
                } else {
                        echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"" . $row['Libraries'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":" . $row['Count'] . ",\"f\":null}]}, ";
                }
        }
        echo " ] }";
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Do you send `Content-type: application/json` headers before your JSON output in `getpiechartdata.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to see what's happening under the hood is by using the web inspector (dev tools) in your browser.

1. In Google Chrome, open the dev tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) and click the `Network` tab.
2. Invoke your Ajax request (with the dev tools panel open)
3. Click on the request that was just added to the list and inspect it. Pay close attention to the `Headers` and `Response` tabs.

Comment: It seems there was a jquery error. I tried to download the latest jquery and kept it in same folder some how it still can't find it. But then again I changed it to google/ajax/libs and it works now! Thanks again this web inspector will surely come handy!